# localStorage data disappears after the page is refreshed

Tags: angular

I am using a ControlValueAccessor to change my div tag to a form element and I am using localStorage to set and get my data. I am having the problem that my product_name item isn't being saved and after I refresh the page, the product_name disappears. How can I change my code so that the data persists after a page refresh?

In the HTML template:

```
<div class="product_name" name="p_name"></div>
<div name="product_name" (click)="add('Bike')" style="cursor:pointer;">Bike</div>
```

In the controller:

```
add(product_name){
localStorage.setItem("product_name", product_name);
(document.querySelector('.product_name') as HTMLElement).innerText = localStorage.getItem("product_name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, localStorage *should* persist.  I suspect "something else" might be going on...

SUGGESTIONS:

1. This article has some great tips:

   [Persist data using Local Storage and Angular](https://firstclassjs.com/persist-data-using-local-storage-and-angular/)
2. In particular, make an explicit check if local storage is supported in your browser:

   ```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

   @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
   })

   export class LocalStorageService {
     localStorage: Storage;
     ...
     constructor() {
       this.localStorage   = window.localStorage;
     }
     ...
      get isLocalStorageSupported(): boolean {
        return !!this.localStorage
      }
   }
   ```

   3. I would definitely structure your code like the article does.  Specifically, Would recommend putting localStorage access into it's own, separate Angular service.
   4. Add debugging instrumentation into that service (e.g. `console.log()` statements) to ensure everything is "OK" - at least as far as localStorage store, fetch and persist are concerned.